# can use these printer motors to made CNC machine?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, cnc

[image]

can i use this motor to make a cnc plottor ?
is there any way to make a stepper motor using this motor?

Comment: Not realistically, no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That is a simple motor. It cannot be changed into a stepper. To use a simple motor then you will need feedback, an encoder. You will be better off getting real stepper motors or servo motors.